# How to auto close the toast message only on incoming of new toast message?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, toast

**To close the toast message, only when new toast is fired or else it should stick to old toast message.**

Answer (score 6):

You can't. There's no API available for a developer to alter a toast once it has been dispatched, including closing the toast or altering its behavior. You have three basic options here: show the toast until a duration has elapsed, show the toast until the user dismisses it, or show the toast until the duration has elapsed *or* the user dismisses it, whichever occurs first. If you need a more robust toasting mechanism, you'll have to write your own custom component, instead.