# how to clear toasts before showing a new toast

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I am trying to  clear toasts before showing a new toast.

```
showToast.setParams({
                'mode': 'sticky',
                'duration' : '5000',
                'title': 'Please review the below errors',
                'type': 'error',
                'message': errorMessage, });
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no API for controlling the toast after you dispatch force:showToast. You cannot clear old toasts. I just answered a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/223724) that asked about controlling toasts. While this is a slightly different question, the answer is the same. You cannot control standard toasts after dispatching a toast event.